# How to make search work in javascript in laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel

I have a problem in how to make table search working in the javascript code. I have a different scenario. I am getting data through ajax So I need to add table thread in the javascript rather than in the html. But now I want a search for the table. I write also code for that to search but that's only working when my thread is in the html. Below is my code and it will give you a clear view. Try to read it in the editor because its a more complicated :). It is a search for each column

//Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({
      headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
      }
    });
  });

  $('select[name="class_id"]').on('change', function() {
    var classID = $(this).val();
    if (classID) {

      $.ajax({

        url: '/attendance/ajax/' + classID,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {

          var markup = '';
          markup += '<tr><th style="width: 2%" class="align-middle text-center"><input type="checkbox" id="options"></th><th style="width: 2%" class="align-middle text-center">#</th> <th style="width: 15%" class="text-center">Student ID<input type="text" class="form-control" disabled></th> <th style="width: 15%" class="text-center">Student Name<input type="text" class="form-control" disabled></th> <th style="width: 15%" class="text-center">Attendance<input type="text" class="form-control" disabled></th> <th style="width: 15%" class="text-center">Date<input type="text" class="form-control" disabled></th> <th style="width: 15%;" class="align-middle text-center">Actions</th> <tr>';

          $.each(data, function(key, value) {

            markup += '<tr> <td><input class="checkBoxes" type="checkbox" name="checkBoxArray[]"></td> <td><input type="hidden" value="' + value.id + '" name="id[]">' + value.id + '</td> <td><input type="hidden" value="' + value.student_id + '" name="student_id[]">' + value.student_id + '</td> <td><input type="hidden" value="' + value.first_name + '" name="first_name[]"><input type="hidden" value="' + value.last_name + '" name="last_name[]">' + value.first_name + ' ' + value.last_name + '<td><input type="hidden" value="' + value.attendance + '" name="attendance[]">' + value.attendance + '</td>' + '<td><input type="hidden" value="' + value.created_at + '" name="created_at[]">' + value.created_at + '</td>' + '<td style=" width=12%" class="text-center"> <a><button title="Edit" class="btn btn-outline-primary"><span class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></span></button></a> </td>' + '</td> <tr>';

          });
          $('table[id="studentsData"]').html(markup);
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

//Code for search

```
 $('body').on('click', '.filterable .btn-filter', function() {
                var $panel = $(this).parents('.filterable'),
                        $filters = $panel.find('.filters input'),
                        $tbody = $panel.find('.table tbody');
                if ($filters.prop('disabled') == true) {
                    $filters.prop('disabled', false);
                    $filters.first().focus();
                } else {
                    $filters.val('').prop('disabled', true);
                    $tbody.find('.no-result').remove();
                    $tbody.find('tr').show();
                }
            });

        $('body').on('input', '.filterable .filters input', function(e) {
                /* Ignore tab key */
                var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
                if (code == '9') return;
                /* Useful DOM data and selectors */
                var $input = $(this),
                        inputContent = $input.val().toLowerCase(),
                        $panel = $input.parents('.filterable'),
                        column = $panel.find('.filters th').index($input.parents('th')),
                        $table = $panel.find('.table'),
                        $rows = $table.find('tbody tr');
                /* Dirtiest filter function ever ;) */
                var $filteredRows = $rows.filter(function () {
                    var value = $(this).find('td').eq(column).text().toLowerCase();
                    return value.indexOf(inputContent) === -1;
                });
                /* Clean previous no-result if exist */
                $table.find('tbody .no-result').remove();
                /* Show all rows, hide filtered ones (never do that outside of a demo ! xD) */
                $rows.show();
                $filteredRows.hide();
                /* Prepend no-result row if all rows are filtered */
                if ($filteredRows.length === $rows.length) {
                    $table.find('tbody').prepend($('<tr class="no-result text-center"><td colspan="' + $table.find('.filters th').length + '">No Result Found</td></tr>'));
                }
            });
```

//Error
[image]

Comment: see this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43597336/how-create-search-filter-with-laravel-javascript

Comment: Not that's totally a different scenario. He has a problem with values. And i have problem in javascript search which is not working becuase my table thead is in javascript. And i did that because I used ajax for fetching data as you can see

Comment: See the comments in the same question.

Comment: No it does not help

Answer (score 0):

**[Working sample](https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/dyn6q8bL/17/).**

Try to use event delegation `on()` instead like :

```
var body = $('body');

body.on('click', '.filterable .btn-filter', function() {
    alert('----1');
});

body.on('input', '.filterable .filters input', function(e) {
    alert('----2');
});
```

Comment: Sir it is giving me the duplicated Jquery selector

Comment: It is giving me that error in the editor and same result in the browser

Comment: update the question with the last version of your JS code and the screenshot of the error.

Comment: It's not an error, it's just a warning, could be bypassed by declaring the body at the top check my updated answer.

Comment: same result. And let me clear that my search button is in the html

Comment: I need more information about this, try to add just alerts inside the events as my updated answer do, to check if the code is reached or not.

Comment: Yes the alert is working. It showing me that 1 alert

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191455/discussion-between-zakaria-acharki-and-hasnain-kahn).